# mapping a JSON string into an NSDate object using RestKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, restkit, nsdateformatter

I have a `JSON` that contains a date object like this.

```
date: "22/02/2014"
```

Now I want to map it into an `NSDate` object. So in my mapping I've added this.

```
 NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];

    kalenderMapping.dateFormatters = [NSArray arrayWithObject: dateFormatter];
```

When I log my `NSDate` object I get this.

```
date is 3112-12-31 23:00:00 +0000
```

Anybody got an idea what the problem is?

Thanks !

EDIT

This is how I use kalenderMapping.

First off all here is my entire function.

```
-(RKObjectManager *)mapGetKalender{
    RKEntityMapping* kalenderMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Kalender" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    kalenderMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"kal_date"] ;
    [kalenderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"date": @"kal_date",
        @"hour": @"kal_hour",
        @"type": @"kal_type",
        @"home": @"kal_home",
        @"away": @"kal_away",
        @"homeScore": @"kal_homeScore",
        @"awayScore": @"kal_awayScore",
        @"homeIcon": @"kal_homeIcon",
        @"awayIcon": @"kal_awayIcon",
        @"date_text": @"kal_date_text",

     }];
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"dd/M/yyyy"];

    kalenderMapping.dateFormatters = [NSArray arrayWithObject: dateFormatter];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:kalenderMapping
                                                                                       pathPattern:nil
                                                                                           keyPath:@"sportief.calendar"                                                                                       statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

     NSArray *arrResponsDescriptor = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:responseDescriptor, nil];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:arrResponsDescriptor];
    return objectManager;

}
```

This returns an objectManager. That objectmanager I am going to use like this.

```
-(void)fetchKalender{
    API *api = [API new];
    RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[YellowstarsDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [api mapGetKalender];
    NSString *request = @"/mobile/json/request/calendar/type/ipad";

    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:request parameters:nil
                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                NSError *error = nil;
                                BOOL success = [store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext  save:&error];
                                if (!success) RKLogWarning(@"Failed saving managed object context: %@", error);
                                NSLog(@"DONE FETCHING");

                            }
                            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                               delegate:nil
                                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                [alert show];
                                NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
                            }];
    NSError *error = nil;

    [context save:&error];
}
```

After executing this function I suppose that all my dates are stored as NSDates in my core database no ?

Comment: You need to explain how the kalendarMapping value is used to map the date.  You also need to use "yyyy" rather than "YYYY".

Comment: I've edited my question. If you need more information, please ask !

Comment: What date format are you actually using as the question now shows 2 different versions...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"dd/M/yyyy"];
```

And also put the code where you create the date with the formatter.

Comment: What do you mean with "also put the code where you create the date with the formatter" ?

Comment: Where should I put this code? not where I do my mapping I suppose ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *date = @"22/02/2014";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
```

I think the above code will work for you...